# How to optimize jquery cdn load time for mobile score?

Tags: jquery, performance, optimization, cdn, google-pagespeed

I'm trying to optimize a web site to score above 90 on google page insights both on mobile and desktop. Now my desktop score is fine but on mobile I get around 80 and the main reason for that according to google test is **Reduce the impact of third-party code Third-party code blocked the main thread for** which is jquery CDN load time. It is loaded through google CDN and I've been trying for 3 days now to find a solution online but no luck. I cannot `defer` or `async` it as it breaks my site. Can anyone shed some light on how to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: The best way to do this is not use a CDN. It will mean you will need to download and host the libraries on your Web Server. This will make the code no longer Third Party, or hosted by another server, requiring another HTTP request by the client.

Comment: `defer` should not break your site if you add `defer` to everything. The trick to stop code blocking the thread however is code splitting and that is quite a complex process if you haven't tried it before as you need to split out the JS required for "above the fold" content and the JS required for everything else. Best advice is to `defer` all JS, add `rel="preload"` for key resources and then leave it and focus on other performance improvements. Other than that, don't use jQuery as it is massive and instead use vanilla JS or micro libraries (that is a huge undertaking I wouldn't recommend)

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Super easy, it did not even occur to me to add `defer` to my main,js file as it was not mentioned in any of the speed tests that I ran. But now that I think of it it makes a whole lot of sense. And suddenly my TBT is green, thanks a lot

Comment: Not a problem at all, glad it helped! Yeah the `defer` thing catches a load of people out as it doesn't explain how it changes the execution order and breaks any dependencies. You aren't the first (and won't be the last) to make that mistake!  Oh and stay clear of `async` as that can be a nightmare to implement on existing code! Good luck with the project!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I've came to a solution and decided to post it here, maybe someone finds it helpful in the future.
So adding `defer` to the script did help but one out of three page speed insight checks would still come over **500ms for total blocking time**. So what I did was copy the jquery code and added it directly to `<script></script>` tags in the header of the file. Every check from then on was **0-40ms** on mobile **0-20ms** for desktop.